# Programmatically expire all sessions on Java web application restart

Tags: java, session, servlets

I need a way to disable session persistence on tomcat restarts that can be bundled inside the application.

So I figured out the best way to do it would be programmatically.

The problem is I cannot find a way of simply keeping a Collection of sessionids as a property of an application scoped serializable bean and iterate over those, retrieving (recovering from persistent storage and deserializing) the session object corresponding to each sessionid in order to destroy it.

Instead it seems the only solution is to keep the same Collection but with the whole session objects.

How can I avoid that and still be able to destroy all the session objects on application restart or whenever I please in a way independent of the servlet container?

Comment: "Whole session Object" - I hope you realize that you won't be cloning the session objects but keeping references to those objects. This won't add a large footprint to your collection/map.

Comment: but won't they be stored in memory for as long as references are kept in active beans?

Comment: what I mean is that I don't want to have hundreds or even thousands of session beans just sitting there in memory doing nothing just because their sessions haven't expired yet when no more than a few of them belong to active sessions. I want them to be serialized and stored on persistent storage when no bean is using them and having a reference to them on an application bean will prevent that. Maybe I don't get it right... Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are correct. I did not think of that. Perhaps you could use a periodic job to clear the invalid sessions from your map.

Comment: That's more or less what I want. As soon as the app (re)starts every persisted session belonging to the prior execution of that app is invalid. No matter if it's expired or not. What I want is a way to (programmatically) delete all of them.

Comment: Why wouldn't you do it using the Tomcat configurations? Anyway, in case you have persistent sessions enabled, you'll have to delete the file where the sessions are serialized and persisted upon tomcat restart. Memory based (map/collection) approach will not help because upon restart, the session objects will be recreated.

Comment: This is actually more interesting than I originally thought. I'd like to know if there is a way to tell when the application was restarted. Because if you can get the time of the restart and you stored the time of session creation in the session, you can then invalidate any session that was created before the restart.

Comment: @TJ There are 2 reasons why I want to avoid Tomcat configs: They have to be set on every deployment and some deployments might use a different servlet container (glassfish, wildfly or jetty)

Comment: Wrap requests with filter and override getSession method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've ended up doing:

I've kept indeed a serializable application scoped bean with a serializable property: A Hashtable whose keys are the session ids and values the timestamps of creation (I've used Long instead of Timestamp to minimize the memory footprint).

I am using an [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) implementation to populate that Hashtable and eliminate the expired sessions on its sessionCreated and sessionDestroyed methods.

The bean has a @PostConstruct method that gets that table and sets all the values to 0.

And here's the nasty part:

Every time I want to use the session object (for example, after a request.getSession()) I have to "manually" invoke a method that checks if the value on this table is 0 and if it is expire the session and create a new one.

There has to be a better way to do it, or a reason why this shouldn't be done. Please let me know if you know of one.

Comment: You could probably get rid of the session listener and hashtable as HttpSession has a method getCreationTime(). Since you're already calling some function after request.getSession() you could make it use the creation time from there.

Comment: You might then need a startup servlet whose init() method sets a static member of some class to the time the application started and you can compare the session create time to that.

Comment: that would work too, but the main problem remains; I need to do the check  every time I get the session object. What I would like is a way to do that automatically, like a listener or an override or a wrapper...